# How to remove SWAP partition, and add back to root partition in cli

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, partition, swap, parted

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 server with only ssh access into the machine in question.

Someone else setup this machine, and they added a ridiculous swap space...a little more than half of the SSD.  Here's the current setup.

```
sdb            119.2G    disk
  |
  ---->sdb1    512M      part  /boot/efi
  |
  ---->sdb2    55G       part  /
  |
  ---->sdb3    63.8G     part  [SWAP]
```

I don't need any swap space at all.  This machine has pleanty of RAM, and the swap space is never used.  I'd like to remove the sdb3 partition, and add that 63.8G of space into sdb2.

I've used gparted several times, but only on desktops with UI's, and never in a terminal.

Can anyone give me some advice on a safe way to perform this transition?

Comment: Is the swap partition actually  adjacent to the root partition on your disk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found that it is easier and safer to do a compressed tar backup, re-install the OS to your new configuration and then restore the files.

Also, no matter how much RAM, I still leave 4GB for swap because you don't know what other machine might be running those disks in the future.

But you are right, 63GB for swap is very high these days.

Comment: So, this doesn't really answer the question, so maybe someone will answer it later...but it does make me think I didn't ask the right question.  I should have asked which is easier, and this is probably true.  I'll just start over.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can forward X11 through ssh and open gparted GUI in your client.
If your client is a Windows machine, you can use putty and xming. An example guide can be http://www.geo.mtu.edu/geoschem/docs/putty_install.html

Once you have configured Xming and putty, open session with putty to your server, launch "sudo gparted" (if it is installed, if not, install it ;) from the command line and you will get the gparted ui in your machine.